# Writing better JUnit Parameterized test cases

Tags: java, junit, junit4, hamcrest

I have an interesting requirement. I want to have as better test case coverage as possible in my application. I am using Parameterized Junit to run testcases with number of different inputs. My sample test class looks like this:

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> testInputs()
{
    return Arrays.asList({
        {1, CoreMatchers.is(1)},
        {2, CoreMatchers.is(2)}
    });
}
@Test
public test()
{
    myApp.run(); 
    assertThat(myApp.getA(), matcher);
}
```

This way, I defined the assertion logic with my test parameters. Now I want to run multiple matchers on the test case, some of them can be custom matchers which I wrote.

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> testInputs()
{
    return Arrays.asList({
        {1, Arrays.asList( CoreMatchers.is(1), CustomMatchers.status(1) ) },
        {2, Arrays.asList( CoreMatchers.is(2), CustomMatchers.status(2) ) }
    });
}
```

And assertion is like:

```
for(Matcher<MyApp> matcher: matchers)
{
    assertThat(myApp, matcher);
}
```

But the problem is, both the matchers run on different objects. What is the best way I can define my CustomMatcher ??

Should I categorize the assertion by type of matcher?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "both the matchers run on different objects," but you can combine the matchers for a single test run using [`CoreMatchers.allOf`](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/AllOf.java). This way you don't need to loop over a list of matchers and can pass any number of matchers, including one.

```
@Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> testInputs()
{
    return Arrays.asList({
        {1, CoreMatchers.allOf( CoreMatchers.is(1), CustomMatchers.status(1) ) },
        {2, CoreMatchers.allOf( CoreMatchers.is(2), CustomMatchers.status(2) ) }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I think you would be better using pure `java.lang` objects rather than JUnit objects as the parameters. So

```
return Arrays.asList({
    {1, 1},
    {2, 2}
});
```

and use the `is` matcher in the actual test.

If the matchers are doing really different things, don't use a parameterized test, just use a separate test method. To reduce duplication, use the usual refactoring tools to extract common methods between test methods.